# nested node struct inside binary search tree return value problem c++

Tags: c++, function, class, oop, tree

I`ve made this tree class:

```
 #ifndef BST_H_
#define BST_H_

#include <iostream>
#include "treeExceptions.h"

typedef int T;
typedef struct vertice vertice;

    #ifndef BST_H_
#define BST_H_

#include <iostream>
#include "treeExceptions.h"

typedef int T;
typedef struct vertice vertice;



class BST
{
    private:
        struct vertice
    {
        private:
        protected:
        public:
        T data;
        vertice* left;
        vertice* right;
        vertice():left(nullptr),right(nullptr),data(0){};
        vertice(const T& val):left(nullptr),right(nullptr),data(val){};
    };
    static vertice* auxErase(vertice* root,const T& val);
    
    protected:
    vertice* root;
    static vertice* findSuccessor(vertice* root);
    static bool Contain(vertice* root,const T& val);
    static void auxPrintInOrder(vertice* root);
    static void auxInsert(vertice* root,const T& val);
    void EmptyTree(vertice* root);

    public:

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    explicit BST():root(nullptr){};
    //DESTRUCTOR
    ~BST();
    void insert(const T& val);
    void erase(const T& val);
    bool find(const T& val);
    void printInOrder();
};
```

I`ve made a bunch of "aux" functions so the user will not have to handle with nodes at all.

in two of my functions 'findSuccessor' and 'auxErase' the return value is 'vertice*'.
I tried to place the 'vertice' struct inside the class but when I do it I will receive a compliation error:

> candidate is: static BST::vertice* BST::auxErase(...)
> struct BST::vertice is private within this context

If I change the reutrn value to any other than 'vertice*' it will not show any error

edit: I changed the code to the one which gives me compliation error

Comment: You don't define a type `BST::vertice`. That structure is defined (by the looks of it) in the global scope.

Comment: Furthermore, in C++ all structure and class names are also types, which means you don't need the `typedef struct vertice vertice;` alias definition.

Comment: You can place the struct in the class, but it must be public.
Edit: I see now that the methods are also private. Can you post the actual code that doesn't compile?

Comment: Just made an edit to the code still get the same problem